# jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).autosize is not a function TypeError: $(...).autosize is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, autosize

The autosize property isn't working

```
    <div id="wrapper">

    
            <textarea placeholder="Saisir le texte à diacritiser" id="name-input" name="text" rows="4" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 160px; "></textarea>  
            <br>
            <input id="name-button" type="submit" value="Diacritiser">
            <h1 id="output"></h1>

    
    </div>


    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

here start the JS code

```
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#title').focus();
            $('#name-input').autosize();
        })});

        $("#name-button").click(function(event){
            console.log($("#name-input").val())
            let message = {
                name: $("#name-input").val()
            }
            $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/execute", JSON.stringify(message), function(response){
                $("#output").text(response.output);
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

i tried all the solution in stackoverflow but none worked for me

Comment: Are you loading a file for the autosize plugin? If you are,  then also make sure you are only loading jQuery.js once

Comment: Note that `jQuery(function($)` does exactly the same thing as `$(document).ready` so need to duplicate it